# Get Top 5 latest records for different IDs in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table named Work_Items like this:

[image]

Assume there are lots of Names (i.e., E,F,G,H,I etc.,) and their respective Date and Produced Items in this table. It's a massive table, so I'd want to write an optimised query.

In this, I want to query the latest A,B,C,D records.

I was using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Work_Items WHERE Name IN ('A','B','C','D') ORDER BY Date DESC OFFSET 0 LIMIT 4
```

But the problem with this query is, since I'm ordering by Date, the latest 4 records I'm getting are:

[image]

I want to get this result:

[image]

Please help me in modifying the query. Thanks.

Comment: Don't ask a question tagged MySQL and asking about SQL and then edit it to be about Azure CosmosDB after answers have already been posted. If you have a CosmosDB question ask a new question about that

Comment: Okay. Sorry for that. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
    FROM Work_Items
    WHERE Name IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
)

SELECT Name, Date, ProducedItems
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Name;
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Any idea how it would translate in Azure CosmosDB?

Comment: No idea.  You tagged for MySQL and you got a MySQL answer.

Comment: I'm sorry. I actually wanted it for CosmosDB. I edited it. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner join as follows, its working on any mysql version:

```
select w.name, w.`date`, w.ProducedItems
from _Work_Items w
inner join (
    select name, max(date) as `date`
    from _Work_Items
    group by name
) as s on s.name = w.name and s.`date` = w.`date` ;
```

Comment: I edited the question to get answer for CosmosDB instead of MySQL. If you can translate this to that, I'll accept your answer. Either way, Thank you for your help.

Comment: never used CosmosDB, did a little search found that `inner join` must be changed to `join` maybe it will work ! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/join